# jquery onclick open all the divs in php while

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm building a board of adds, that every add - you can contact the sender by clicking on a button - "message", and a hidden div will be toggle.
I representing the adds by a php while, and I have an index - `i` that starts from 1.
The problem is : When I click on "message" - It toggle all the div's in the page, instead of only the preferable click.
This is the div :

```
<div id="sendtransfer<?php echo $i; ?>" class="send-new_message-transfer">
<span class=close>X</span>
<script>
    $(".close").click(function(){
       $("#sendtransfer<?php echo $i; ?>").hide();
    });
</script>
<h2>Send Message</h2>
<?php
$user_post_id = $_COOKIE['arr']['id'];
?>
<form action='' method='Post'>
    <input type='text' name='to' id="to<?php echo $i; ?>"  maxlength='20' pattern='.{1,20}' required title='1 characters minimum' class='input'><br>
    <input type='text' name='to_name' id="to_fname<?php echo $i; ?>" maxlength='20' class='input' disabled="disabled"><br>
    <input type='text' name='subject' maxlength='50' pattern='.{3,50}' required title='3 characters minimum, 50 maximum' class='input'><br>
    <textarea type='text' name='message' rows='6' cols='30' maxlength='200' pattern='.{1,200}' required title='1 characters minimum' class='input'></textarea><br>
    <input type='submit' value='send message' class='input'>
</form></div>
```

And this is how I Toggle the div :

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.callme').click(function(){
        var username_to_delivered = document.getElementById('delivery_username_to<?php echo $i; ?>').value;
        var fname_to_delivered = document.getElementById('delivery_fname_to<?php echo $i; ?>').value;
        $("#to<?php echo $i; ?>").val(username_to_delivered);
        $("#to_fname<?php echo $i; ?>").val(fname_to_delivered);
        $("#sendtransfer<?php echo $i; ?>").slideToggle();
    });
}); </script>

<input type="text" id="delivery_username_to<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"><input type="text" id="delivery_fname_to<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['fname']; ?>"><button class="callme" id="input-button-message">Message</button>
```

I have no idea why its sliding all the div's - No matter on which one I click.
Thank You!

Comment: What does the actual *client-side* code look like?  Are you really outputting this same JavaScript over and over in a loop?

Comment: I'm doing this because every div id should be unique, if not - It will open always the same div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *all of this* is being emitted in a loop, then this should result in unique ID values:

```
<div id="sendtransfer<?php echo $i; ?>" class="send-new_message-transfer">
```

And this should be identifying them by those unique ID values:

```
$("#sendtransfer<?php echo $i; ?>").slideToggle();
```

That part is probably working.  However, what about this?

```
$('.callme').click(function(){
```

Every time you run that in your loop, you're adding a new click handler to the *same* set of matching elements.  So any click on a `.callme` element is going to invoke *every* one of these click handlers.

Take the JavaScript out of the loop.  You should emit the markup in a loop, but should have *one* JavaScript handler for all similar elements and functionality.  When that handler is invoked, dynamically determine which elements to show/hide/etc.

So if you click on a `.callme` element, from that element how do you find the `div` to show?  It's not clear from your code, but if they're arranged in some pattern then it should be identifiable.  For example, if the `.callme` element is always just before the `div` then you can find that `div`:

```
$(this).next('div[id^="sendtransfer"]').slideToggle();
```

This would identify the next element of type `div` where the ID begins with `"sendtransfer"`.  There are [lots of selector options](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [lots of DOM traversal functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).  You don't have to rely *only* on ID values.

The idea is that there would be one click handler to perform one kind of action and any pattern needed to identify elements for that action would be performed in that handler.  Rather than copying/pasting the *same* code over and over in a loop.